# set margin for only first tab in bootstrap tabs using first-of-type css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, css-selectors

```
.nav-tabs > li:first-of-type > a,
            .nav-tabs > li.active:first-of-type > a,
            .nav-tabs > li.active:first-of-type > a:hover,
            .nav-tabs > li.active:first-of-type > a:active,
            .nav-tabs > li.active:first-of-type > a:focus{
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
```

i am trying to set the margin for first tab only to 10px, but the above css sees to make the margin to 10px whichever one is selected. 
what am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `active` class. This is a default Bootstrap class that represents the currently active element. Remove that from your selectors

```
.nav-tabs > li:first-of-type > a,
        .nav-tabs > li:first-of-type > a,
        .nav-tabs > li:first-of-type > a:hover,
        .nav-tabs > li:first-of-type > a:active,
        .nav-tabs > li:first-of-type > a:focus{
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
```

Comment: didn't really help for some reason